# Paint cracked lines

Tags: paint

Hello someone’s painted my roof black and it’s gone like this how would I remove the black paint so it’s back to silver again [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It hasn’t been primered someone’s just got a can and sprayed the top of it black and where it’s been in the sun it’s cracked the black spray paint so I was thinking off sanding it down then cut and compound it

Answer (score 1):

There'd be just about no way to remove on the black paint to get it back to silver without repainting. Your best bet, to do it the cheapest, is to sand the entire area down to primer, then take it to a body shop and have them go through the actions of spraying new paint down to match the rest of the vehicle. They may have to do more work to get it right, such as prepping the surface filling/blocking/sanding/primer/sealing/painting/top coat. There really is no easy way to do it and make it look decent.

Comment: Yep this ^ The upside is that being a roof it's a fairly simple panel to paint and won't require much (if any) blending

Comment: @motosubatsu - It looks like the panel is divided out by the roof lines and the front/back glass, so yah, blending will definitely be at a minimum.

Comment: Hopefully there isn't a line of weld where 2 cars have been welded together.

Comment: Yeah that was my thinking - which is a win as silver is an utter PITA to get blended well!

Comment: It hasn’t been primed it’s just been painted there was no sanding there aswell